# Combine two commands in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, alias, function

In my `.bash_profile` file, I'd like to setup a single command alias that is two commands that execute one after another. The first command takes an argument from the command line and the second is actually script (located in `~/bin` with execute permissions).

My profile file has this:

```
alias pd='function pd2() { pushd "$@"; set_title_tab; }'
```

I attempt to execute it in the shell like so:

```
$ pd ~/Documents/
```

and I get an error:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `~/Documents/'

`set_title_tab` is a [shell script written by William Scott](http://sage.ucsc.edu/mystuff/zsh/man/settab.html)

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[aliases](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080) do not support input parameters, and there's no need to wrap functions in aliases. Simply use a function:

```
pd() {
    pushd "$@"
    set_title_tab
}

pd ~/Documents
```

Comment: @StephanKeene: This answer is correct, you don't need an alias for this. You can define functions in your bash profile and call them just like other command names or aliases from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Why not this:

```
pd () { pushd "$@"; set_title_tab; }
```

What you have right now is a function definition inside an alias which is ... unusual.  Once you define a function (like I did with `pd` above) you can use it just like any other command.